# Bash script to automatically re-run PHP file?

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I can create a bash script that runs a PHP file over and over with a 3 second delay like this:

```
php -q /home/script.php
sleep 3
php -q /home/script.php
sleep 3
php -q /home/script.php
```

But I'm looking for a better way to do this, so I don't have to create a file with hundreds of thousands of lines and then check to see when it's done so I can just restart it.

Is there any way to create a loop that runs a PHP file and once it's done, it just does it again - for an infinite amount of time (with a 3 second delay between each run)?

Comment: I'm curious as to what task would need to be run that often.  There's a chance that taking action based on event happening, instead of checking every 3 seconds to see if that event happened, may be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Cronjob**

What Are Cron Jobs? https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/what-are-cron-jobs

A cron job is the scheduled task itself. Cron jobs can be very useful to automate repetitive tasks.

Some useful tool for cronjobs: https://crontab.guru/

An example: "run a script every 1 minute"

```
*/1 * * * * bin/php /path/to-your/script.php
```

**Looping**

In case you really need to repeat a task each X seconds, you could write a while loop for that:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  # Do something
  sleep 3;
done
```

Comment: True that. In case you want to go for "seconds" I would do a while loop with some sleep inside... but is way more common to repeat certain task after X minutes, more than X seconds...

Comment: Yeah, but the OP wants seconds, so cron doesn't seem a good option here.

Comment: I edited my answer to display the two options that came to my mind so far.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider writing a while loop:

```
while true
do
  php -q /home/script.php
  sleep 3 
done
```

Comment: I definitely prefer cron as a solution, but you will learn that cron only has minute resolution.